# Same Origin Policy violated on localhost with falcon webserver

Tags: python, web-services, cross-domain, elm, falconframework

I am running an elm frontend via elm-reactor on `localhost:8000`. It is supposed to load json files from a **falcon backend** running via gunicorn on `localhost:8010`. This fails.

The frontend is able to load static dummy files served by elm-reactor (`:8000`) but when I try to replace the dummies by the actual backend (`:8010`) it fails due to a missing header:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:8010/api/sheets. (Reason: CORS
>   header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

The error message from the Firefox Inspector seems reasonably clear, but I'm at a loss how to fix that. I already installed a CORS middleware in falcon, but that didn't improve the situation at all.

```
from falcon_cors import CORS
cors = CORS(allow_origins_list=['*'])
api = falcon.API(middleware=[cors.middleware])
```

I did also try to use the origins `'localhost:8000'` and `'localhost'` but neither works.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that falcon_cors offers `allow_all_origins=True` as a parameter. This fixes my problem, but isn't a perfect solution.

When using POST requests as well `allow_all_methods=True` should be set as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hopefully, this will solve your problem.

```
import falcon
from falcon_cors import CORS
cors = CORS(allow_origins_list=['http://localhost:8080', 'http://localhost:8000', 'http://localhost:8010'], allow_all_headers=True, allow_methods_list=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
api = falcon.API(middleware=[cors.middleware])
```